# Append Numpy Array post Creation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, zero

After creating a `numpy` array, I'm looking to append post creation:

```
numpy_array = np.zeros(2,3)

numpy_array[0][1].append(4,5)
```

Where the output for `numpy_array[0][1]` would be `[0,4,5]`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Is there any way to create a set of arrays you can later append additional values to with numpy?

Comment: Do you need integer  array?

Comment: I could use integer or string but prefer integer

Comment: @AndreL, Did you check that?

Comment: You can't do that with an array like `numpy_array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2d array of any type like this:

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]
```

For your purpose:

```
>>> Matrix = [[ [0] for x in range(3)] for x in range(2)] 
>>> Matrix[0][1]+=[4,5]
>>> Matrix
[[[0], [0, 4, 5], [0]], [[0], [0], [0]]]
```

Comment: Note that this answer uses Python lists, not numpy arrays.  And for this task that probably a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `numpyp.zeros(2,3)` you will get a `TypeError` (Posting bellow with the code the correct way to use it).

You can copy to *numpy* array of `[0. 0. 0.]` the `[4, 5]` list using:

```
np.zeros([2,3]) #note the arg is a list type 
numpy_array[0][1:3] = [4,5]
```

This `[1:3]` get the positions interval.